# No *.bbl file generated by bibtex under emacs

Tags: bibtex, emacs

I can't seem to figure out why my emacs/latex setup fails to produce a *.bbl file for generating references and in text citations. What makes this problem strange is that my setup works for a while i.e. my final output includes a nicely texed file with correct in text citations and a reference page, but then, as of lately, seems to quit on me. I can't recall doing anything strange to my configuration such as editing the '.emacs' file etc..

Symptoms

'LaTeX: there were unresolved citations, {5} pages'

'BibTeX finished successfully. Run LaTeX again to get citations right.'

'LaTeX: there were unresolved citations, {5} pages'

No *.bbl file is generated in my working directory.

Setup

OSX 10.6.8, Emacs-23.3-modified-3 by [Vincent Goulet](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/) and MacTeX-2011. I'm using Mendeley to manage my *.bib files and all files are stored in a dropbox share folder.

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document} 


\citep[pg. 2]{copes2009criminological}. 


\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{/Users/userName/Desktop/dropbox/bibTex/SOCIO862}
\end{document}
```

Actions

latex
bibtex
latex
view
open output-file-name.pdf

Note: I'm pretty sure the command 'latex' in the Actions list actually means pdflatex. I don't get *.dvi files when I run the above sequence of commands and *.eps image files don't compile into the final document though *.png or *.pdf work fine.

Current solution 1

Apparently deleting and reinstalling the Emacs applications sets thing back to working order, but this really isn't a good solution.

Current solution 2

I don't have this problem under texmaker or texworks. Everything works OK. I could give up emacs and use an alternative tex editors, but I've gotten comfortable with the short keys.

Log file notes

'Package natbib Warning: Citation `citation-key' on page 2 undefined 
on input line 64.'

Comment: Not familiar with the `.bll` file name extension; did you maybe mean `.bbl` or `.blg`? If BibTeX is encountering problems, its log file (.blg) might provide a clue.

Comment: You're right, I meant .bbl. I'll update the post. Thanks for catching that one.

Comment: This works fine for me (if you fix the mismatched braces in your `\section` command).  What kind of out put do you see if, after running (pdf)latex (`C-c C-c`) on the file, you hit `C-c C-l` (so emacs splits into two buffers) and then run bibtex (same command)?  Also note that your example is not really as minimal as it could be.  (Please note that I'm using AUCTeX by default, but this shouldn't matter for bibliography generation, though the `(pdf)latex` and `bibtex` commands might be run by a slightly different command.)

Comment: Thanks for tips! It was an Emacs error. I found a solution and everything seems to be working again, though I don't know why it failed in the first place.